# pandas dataframe function mean() not working correctly to ignore nan values

Tags: pandas

By default, the mean() method should ignore the nan value, but for my case, it didn't work. It still takes the nan value.

```
a = np.array([1,9])
b = np.array([3,nan])
c = np.array([7,8])
d = {'value': [a,b,a,c], 'group': [3,3,4,4], 'garbage':['asd','acas','asdasdc','ghfas']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

```
OUTPUT:
value   group   garbage
0   [1, 9]  3   asd
1   [3.0, nan]  3   acas
2   [1, 9]  4   asdasdc
3   [7, 8]  4   ghfas
```

```
for i,j in df.groupby('group')['value']:
    print(j.mean())
    print("=========")
```

```
OUTPUT:
[ 2. nan]
=========
[4.  8.5]
=========
```

Comment: `mean` only ignores the values of the DataFrame that are NaN objects. In your case, the values of the 'value' column are numpy arrays that may contain NaNs. They are not NaNs themselves, so `mean` doesn't ignore them.

Comment: Oh right... thanks! Do you have any suggestion to figure this out :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here, but Ill take a stab at it.

Firstly, the `values` column is a column of numpy arrays, so it is two dimensional. Then when you run `groupby`, `j` becomes a `pd.Series` of numpy arrays. Thus, when you call `mean` you are taking the mean by aligning the axes of the numpy arrays. This is pretty unadvisable because these objects can change shape which will cause an error.

I think what you are trying to do is take the mean across all the arrays in each group. You can do that with.

```
for i,j in df.groupby('group')['value']:
    print(np.nanmean(np.concatenate(j.values)))
```

Whatever you are trying to do, it is going to be way easier to interact with once you combine the values in your loop.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just converted the pd.series into list and np.nanmean works just fine. Your method is also viable!

I am new to pandas so I do not know that the pd.series in each loop is not originally combined XD.

Again, thank you very much for your help!